# SwiftUI: add border to view without bleeding out?

Tags: swiftui

I have a simple view like this:

```
struct TestView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Button(action: {}) {
            Text("Button")
                .padding()
                .foregroundColor(.white)
            
        }
        .background(Color(.gray))
//        .cornerRadius(10)
        .overlay(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                .stroke(.red, lineWidth:4)
        )
        
    }
       
}
```

It draws this:

[image]

I am trying to understand why the border bleeds out of the view (gray area). I want to draw the border so it stays inside the view (in the gray area). It looks like half of its width is out and Half in.

How can I make the border stay inside the overlay bounds?

Comment: do you want just the rounded area and no gray corners?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How can I make the border stay inside the overlay bounds?

Use [`strokeBorder(_:lineWidth:antialiased:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/insettableshape/strokeborder(linewidth:antialiased:)) instead — this draws an inner stroke.

```
Button(action: {}) {
    Text("Button")
        .padding()
        .foregroundColor(.white)
}
.background(Color(.gray))
.overlay(
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
        .strokeBorder(.red, lineWidth: 4) /// here!
)
```

[image: Red border is inside gray area]

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to look like this:
[image]

```
        Button(action: {}) {
            Text("Button")
                .padding()
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
        .background(Color(.gray))
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius:10))
        .overlay(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                .strokeBorder(.red, lineWidth: 4) /// here!
        )
```

Comment: I think OP just wants the border to be inside the bounds, he colors button background gray just to see button bounds I think